# What @{hash{$key}} mean in Perl?

Tags: perl, hashtable

Could someone tell me that what `@{hash{$key}}` means? and whether I was it right when I wrote `@{hash{$key}}[$i]=$list[$i+1]`?

Answer (score 7):

```
@{hash{$key}}
```

is a weird way to write

```
@hash{$key}
```

This is called a hash slice. It allows you to fetch multiple values from a hash in one go. For example,

```
say for @hash{'a', 'b'};
```

means

```
say for $hash{a}, $hash{b};
```

So it's rather silly to use

```
@hash{$key}
```

instead of

```
$hash{$key}
```

---

`@{hash{$key}}[$i]=$list[$i+1];` doesn't compile, so no, it wasn't correct to use it.

Answer (score 4):

As ikegami explains, `@{hash{$key}}` is a hash slice (of only one element).

It is likely that you want this instead: `@{$hash{$key}}`.  If each element of your hash is an array reference, this syntax would allow you to access the array.

For example, suppose your hash contained arrays, like this:

```
my %hash = (
    foo => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    bar => [qw/baz sproing blargh/] 
);
```

`@{$hash{foo}}` would be `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`

If that is the case, then this syntax would work:

```
${$hash{$key}}[$i]=$list[$i+1]
```

Note that you are only accessing an element of the array, not the whole array.  Thus you use `${$hash{$key}}` instead of `@{$hash{$key}}`.

Another way of doing the same thing is this:

```
$hash{$key}->[$i]=$list[$i+1]
```

The `->` syntax for dereferencing is often preferable to `${...}`, because it is cleaner, especially when you have a complex data structure.